# IREDMAIL - Install on Ubuntu with Existing Webserver - PHP,NGINX,MYSQL

Tags: server, php, email, nginx

I'm hosting my website on a VPS with an existing webserver configuration: PHP, NGINX, MYSQL.

The first time I installed `iredmail`, I followed [this tutorial](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/ubuntu-16-04-iredmail-server-installation).

It ended up overwriting all my `nginx/site` configuration and I had to roll-back everything. I was wondering if it's possible to install it on the same server as my website and be only available at `website.com/mail`. I will add the configs manually to `site-enabled`.

Is there also another better/easier way to have a website email address and system? So that I can use `user@website.com`?